# Combining timed data from different sources

Tags: r, time

I have a data set which looks like this (time in seconds):

```
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------+
| Index | Start.Elapsed.Time | End.Elapsed.Time | Outcome |  
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------+
|     1 |                0.0 |              2.5 |       0 |  
|     2 |                2.5 |              5.0 |       0 |  
|     3 |                3.1 |              5.4 |       1 |  
|     4 |                5.0 |              7.5 |       0 |  
|     5 |                7.5 |               10 |       0 |  
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------+
```

As you can see, the timed data is mostly segmented in 2.5 second intervals. However, there are entries (eg: 3) where the time interval is an irregular number, and for all of these entries the outcome is 1. I would like to remove these entries, but add a '1' to the outcome variable for all rows of evenly segmented data that the entry overlaps with (i.e.: 2 and 4). I would like my output table to look like this:

```
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------+
| Index | Start.Elapsed.Time | End.Elapsed.Time | Outcome |  
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------+
|     1 |                0.0 |              2.5 |       0 |  
|     2 |                2.5 |              5.0 |       1 |  
|     4 |                5.0 |              7.5 |       1 |  
|     5 |                7.5 |               10 |       0 |  
+-------+--------------------+------------------+---------+
```

I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Edit: Also, I am working in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can update the 'Outcome' by checking whether the 'Start.Elapsed.Time' is less than the 'End.Elapsed.Time' on the previous row with `lag` and `filter` the rows where there difference of the 'Time' columns are equal to 2.5

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Outcome = +(Start.Elapsed.Time < lag(End.Elapsed.Time, 
          default = first(Start.Elapsed.Time))| 
       as.logical(lead(Outcome, default = 0)))) %>%
    filter(round(End.Elapsed.Time - Start.Elapsed.Time, 1) == 2.5)
#  Index Start.Elapsed.Time End.Elapsed.Time Outcome
#1     1                0.0              2.5       0
#2     2                2.5              5.0       1
#3     4                5.0              7.5       1
#4     5                7.5             10.0       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Index = 1:5, Start.Elapsed.Time = c(0, 2.5, 3.1, 
5, 7.5), End.Elapsed.Time = c(2.5, 5, 5.4, 7.5, 10), Outcome = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```